# Retorno de múltiplas chaves usando REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Estou tentando a leitura de ocorrências de registros de texto baseados em uma ocorrência. Quebrando a cabeça cheguei aos seguintes resultados:

Por exemplo quero pegar o segundo nome, usando como base a chave *empr.:*

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('empr.: 1234 fulano de tal xpto da silva  empr.: 1235 beltrano de tal silveira   empr.: 1236 fulano de tal xpto da silva' , '[^empr.:]\D+',1,2)  FROM dual;
```

Consigo retornar todos os caracteres alfabéticos após o segundo '*empr.:*':

```
5 beltrano de tal silveira empr.:
```

Quando o que preciso é só:

```
beltrano de tal silveira
```

Answer (score 1):

Não ficou muito bonito, mas enfim. Se estiver usando Oracle >= 11g, é possível usar o sexto parâmetro de [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303).

---

Supondo que o valor em questão esteja no `campo` de uma `tabela`:

```sql
select SUBSTR(s, 1, INSTR(s, ' empr.: ') - 1)
from
  (SELECT
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(campo, '\d+ (.+)', INSTR(campo, 'empr.: ', 1, 2) + 7, 1, '', 1) as s
   FROM tabela);
```

`INSTR(campo, 'empr.: ', 1, 2)` pega a segunda ocorrência de "empr. : " e retorna a posição em que ele se encontra. Eu uso 7 posições à frente desta posição (assim já pulo o próprio "empr. ") e uso isso como posição inicial para `REGEXP_SUBSTR`. Por isso eu posso procurar por `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos) seguido de `(.+)` - um ou mais caracteres, e dentro de parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). O sexto parâmetro indica que quero somente o conteúdo deste grupo, ou seja, já consegui eliminar os números aqui.

O resultado do `REGEXP_SUBSTR` pega tudo do "beltrano" pra frente.

Em seguida eu uso `SUBSTR` neste resultado e pego tudo do início até a próxima ocorrência de "empr.: ". O resultado é "beltrano de tal silveira".

[Veja aqui rodando no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e6b4/12).